# python-telegram-bot application exit after long running task in ConversationHandler

Tags: python-telegram-bot

My application close unexpectedly after handling long running task in a `ConversationHandler`.

Here is what I found when run with logging DEBUG. `send_document` works as my expectation ... but after that my application close without any error.

```
2023-03-26 21:55:57,438 - telegram._bot - DEBUG - Exiting: send_document
2023-03-26 21:55:57,440 - telegram.ext._application - DEBUG - Dropping pending updates
2023-03-26 21:55:57,441 - telegram.ext._application - DEBUG - Application stopped fetching of updates.
2023-03-26 21:55:57,441 - telegram.ext._application - DEBUG - Waiting for `create_task` calls to be processed
2023-03-26 21:55:57,441 - telegram.ext._application - INFO - Application.stop() complete
2023-03-26 21:55:57,442 - telegram._bot - DEBUG - This Bot is already shut down. Returning.
2023-03-26 21:55:57,442 - telegram.ext._updater - DEBUG - Shut down of Updater complete
```

I also add error handler to print the traceback but nothing appear in console log.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/MWE).